# Attach an email client to my application

Tags: android

I'd like to add an open source email client to my application. So whenever a user clicks 'open mail' menu option in my application, it will invoke the email client app.

I am pretty unclear of attaching an external application into mine.

How is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want to add a specific application to your application, or is it ok if your application starts the default email client on that phone/tablet/...?

Comment: I must be able to access the email attachments (from where I can download) and add few options in the email client such as 'send via bluetooth'. So once the user press on that option, my application initially downloads the file and send it via bluetooth. Is it possible to edit default email client application and invoke from mine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do it. Please look at this question here:

[What is the purpose of using Intent.createChooser() in StartActivity() while sending email in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804233/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-intent-createchooser-in-startactivity-while-send)

Comment: I tried running in Nexus S. It showed 'No application to pick'

Comment: Have you set up your mail clients on the phone?

Comment: Yes. I have gmail and default email client running in the device. But once I added extra data to intent such as Intent.EXTRA_MAIL, the application listed available email clients. Clicking any of them tok me to compose window. But, I want to modify the email client application and add additional options. Doing as aforementioned would not yield as intended.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can package a modified email client within my application and use as and when required. Do you have any inputs on that?

Comment: I'm really not sure if that's possible. You may need to install a second (email) in addition to your app. You might be able to check if the email app is installed and alert the user to install the app, that's the only way I can think off the top of my head.

Comment: Okay. So if I have email client ready, how can I invoke it from my application?