# Is it possible for ACTION_VIEW with a MIME type of pdf to find no application which could handle it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'd like to use the following code for an application:

```
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(foo), MIME_PDF)

val chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, getString(R.string.view_using))
chooser.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

startActivity(chooser)
```

where

```
const val MIME_PDF = "application/pdf"
```

and the format would be something like:

```
https://example.net/name-of-feature/ThisIsThePdf.pdf
```

On my own device and on an emulator, this will open a nice view for viewing the pdf, seems like it loads a google pdf viewer and it doesn't even open a launcher for picking an application, which is completely fine, however, could it be possible that for certain devices, this request would fail ?

As far as I can tell, this intent is actually just attempting to open anything which could view a pdf and then gives it the data for the pdf, so this intent has no actual dependency on the google pdf viewer, instead it just relies on the user having a browser, or anything else which could process the pdf installed, right ?

In theory then, as long as a user has (at least) a browser installed, this intent will always work ?

Comment: `as long as a user has (at least) a browser installed, ` No. Has nothing to do with browsers as they cannot display pdf documents. You need to have installed a pdf viewer app.

Comment: it's a link towards a url which hosts the pdf

Comment: why is that too vague ? unfortunately i can't provide a URL as its business logic

Comment: cool cool, let me update my question

Comment: If you dont use a mime type a browser will do the job but will probably offer to download the pdf. If you use a pdf mime type a pdf viewer app can be choosen. They mostly cannot download from http except i think Drive pdf viewer.

Comment: well, i have all of this code running on an app, it doesn't offer to download, instead it just opens it into some sort of google pdf viewer, although i'm unsure of which application this is or if it's even installed on the device, it basically seems like an online pdf viewer, which is why i thought it's strange, because it also doesn't show an intent picker for doing this, it just opens it directly, with OR without the mime type

Comment: Maybe you earlier checked 'always use this action' or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never trust that the user will have an application which will be able to open the file you wanted to. You never know what applications user has installed on his/her device and etc.
Always check :

```
try {
    startActivity(chooser)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // Define what your app should do if no activity can handle the intent.
}
```

Better to be prepared instead of crashing the app.

Comment: i suppose this would be the best generic approach and solution to take, regardless of the situation, so i'd be happy to accept this as an answer assuming someone doesn't post anything else. still, it would be really interesting to know if it's possible for this to fail, because it seems to just be passing this to the browser

Comment: @a_local_nobody , if you are looking for a device in which it could fail , I suggest you test this is in rooted device running Lineage OS 16 or 17, it's a minimal android ome and it's default browser doesn't support a pdf viewer.

Comment: Even is the user has installed browser you can't be sure that the one which he is using can handle that intent. Not all phones has installed Chrome as browser for example. The user can also disable certain apps even if they are installed so the system won't let them handle that intent and your application will probably crash.

Comment: thanks for your input @Nitish, i guess i'll try to start an intent with the mime type added and then if that fails i'll remove the mime type as a backup

Comment: Chrome cannot display pdf documents to begin with. And it will certainly not be in the list for application/pdf.

Answer (score 0):

By default it seems like the android emulators come with a pdf viewer installed, which is Google Drive, which was handling my intent automatically. If you wrap your request in `Intent.createChooser` and it finds nothing on the device to handle the request, it won't throw an exception, instead it will just show on the device that no matching app was found to handle the intent, reference - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804233/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-intent-createchooser-in-startactivity-while-sen/11481200)